# Stop sort and change css

Tags: jquery-ui

I have 3 sortable divs. I try to change the height of an item if the user moves it to the right (without sorting). It works well in "sort" this is when the user is moving the item, but when the user leaves the item it comes back to its original height (40px) and I want it to keep the new one (20px). Is it possible to do that?

(Of course I could just put no condition in stop but this is a simplified case and I need a way to detect if in sort the user has moved the item)

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
        sort: function (event, ui) { // during sorting
            var move = (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left);
            $('#desti').text(move);

            if ( move > 30 ) {  
                ui.item.css({height:'20px'}); 
            }
        },

        stop: function(event, ui) { 
            if ( move > 30 ) { 
                ui.item.css({height:'20px'});   
            } 
        }

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item1</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sortable div {
    height:40px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first look at your code you are using `move` variable but it is declared inside `sort:` function
If you declare `move` inside `sort:`, how could you use it in `stop:`

```
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        sort: function (event, ui) { // during sorting
            var move = (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left);// Look At Here
            $('#desti').text(move);
        if ( move > 30 ) {  
            ui.item.css({height:'20px'}); 
        }
    },

    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        if ( move > 30 ) { 
            ui.item.css({height:'20px'});   
        } 
    }

});
```

Just declare it like this...

```
            var move =0;//Declare it here.. or create another move inside stop:
            $("#sortable").sortable({
                sort: function (event, ui) { // during sorting
                    move= (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left);
                    $('#desti').text(move);
                if (move > 30) {
                    ui.item.css({ height: '20px' });
                }
            },

            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //create a move here...
                if (move > 30) {
                    ui.item.css({ height: '20px' });
                }
            }

        });
```